# Serverless Framework not configuring properly Lambda subscription to SNS Topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, serverless-framework

I'm trying to implement this simple architecture with Serverless Framework :

File Upload to S3 Bucket --> SNS Topic --> 2 Lambda Functions

Actually i'm just testing with just 1 lambda function and here is my code:

```
service: MyImageLibrary

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2

package:
  individually: true

functions:
    handler: index.lambda_handler

resources:
  Resources:

ImageUploadedTopic:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
  Properties:
    TopicName: SNSTopicImageUploadedTopic

ImageUploadedTopicSubscription:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
  Properties:
    Endpoint:
      Fn::GetAtt: [ TestLambdaFunction , "Arn" ]
    Protocol: lambda
    TopicArn:
      arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxx:SNSTopicImageUploadedTopic

ImageUploadedTopicPolicy:
  Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
      - Sid: AllowBucketToPushNotificationEffect
        Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service: s3.amazonaws.com
        Action: sns:Publish
        Resource: "*"
    Topics:
      - arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxx:SNSTopicImageUploadedTopic

MyImagesBucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  DependsOn: ImageUploadedTopicPolicy
  Properties:
    BucketName: ${self:custom.bucketName}
    NotificationConfiguration:
      TopicConfigurations:
        - Event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          Topic: 
            arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:SNSTopicImageUploadedTopic
    CorsConfiguration:
      CorsRules:
      - AllowedMethods:
        - GET
        - PUT
        - POST
        - HEAD
        AllowedOrigins:
        - "*"
        AllowedHeaders:
        - "*"
```

In the console i can see that the Lambda function is subscribed to the the Topic :

[image: sns1]

But in the Lambda Function the SNS topic is not set in the Trigger section :

[image: sns2]

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i GOT IT !

I had to add another permission to allow the Lambda function to be triggered by the SNS Topic :

```
TestLambdaFunctionPermission: 
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    Principal: sns.amazonaws.com 
    SourceArn:
      Ref: ImageUploadedTopic
    FunctionName:
      Fn::GetAtt: [ TestLambdaFunction, "Arn" ]
```

And now in the console i can the SNS as trigger for my Lambda function :)